# Vue.JS: Add Subfolder "index.html" pages when running "npm run build"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

I recreated the problem with the vue-starter-project:
When I have routes with subfolders such aus "/about"

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    }
  ]
```

I only get the static "index.html" for the '/' route and not the subfolders, such as '/about' as you can see in the build process:

dist/assets/logo-da9b9095.svg        0.31 kB
dist/index.html                      0.42 kB
dist/assets/AboutView-4d995ba2.css   0.09 kB │ gzip:  0.10 kB
dist/assets/index-81e4655a.css       4.18 kB │ gzip:  1.31 kB
dist/assets/AboutView-10e3979e.js    0.23 kB │ gzip:  0.20 kB
dist/assets/index-415e8d46.js       83.95 kB │ gzip: 33.03 kB

How should I change what file to make it work?

I come from nuxt where all the files are normally build but have to work on this vue project and the new hosting provider is not a node.js provider and throws me a 404 when i try to access the subfolders (cause there are no subfolders generated). I searched already for hours and could not find the solution and it drives me mad.

Comment: You won't get any html file for your routes, the index.html file is used for all routes. You need to redirect to the index.html file, with a .htaccess for example if you are using apache

Comment: Thanks, this is with the configuration from https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations fixed it for me.